# Search for .txt, .scv files in directory in Python

Tags: file, python, glob

I would like to add in a list all the files with an extension .txt and .scv in a given directory in Python.
My current code looks like this:

```
import glob
def core():
  old_path = '/home/demo/'
  files = glob.glob(old_path+(*.{txt, scv}))
  print(len(files))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code - wildcards must be strings. And the second problem is that `glob` doesn't support brace expansion (i.e. it doesn't understand `{txt, csv}`). So you need to use basic wildcards:

```
import glob
def core():
    old_path = '/home/demo/'
    txt_files = glob.glob(old_path+'*.txt')
    csv_files = glob.glob(old_path+'*.csv')
    print(len(txt_files + csv_files))

core()
```